# Correct reading from console in the same line with request

Tags: java, output, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write request, which user can see in console and in the same line he can give response, but I have some issues with that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    final static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run();
    }

    public static void run() {
        System.out.println("GREETINGS");
        handleAccountExistence();
    }

    public static void handleAccountExistence() {
        String response;
        do {
            System.out.print("Do you have an account? (y/n): ");
            response = scanner.nextLine();
        } while (!isValidResponse(response));

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("enter username");
        } else {
            System.out.println("register need");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidResponse(String input) {
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) return true;
        else {
            System.err.println("INVALID_INPUT" + "'y' or 'n'.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to give incorrect response, I get the next:

```
GREETINGS
Do you have an account? (y/n): 45
Do you have an account? (y/n): INVALID_INPUT'y' or 'n'.
45
INVALID_INPUT'y' or 'n'.
Do you have an account? (y/n): 54
Do you have an account? (y/n): INVALID_INPUT'y' or 'n'.
54
INVALID_INPUT'y' or 'n'.
```

Instead of this:

```
GREETINGS
Do you have an account? (y/n): 45 
INVALID_INPUT'y' or 'n'.
Do you have an account? (y/n): 45
INVALID_INPUT'y' or 'n'.
Do you have an account? (y/n):
```

I triesd to use System.out.flush(), .trim(), System.out.println(), but it doesn't help in my case.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get user input with Scanner, and then output text on the same line. I don't think that this is possible with the standard Java Scanner, aside from possibly using OS specific escape codes.

Comment: You need to place the validation within the loop, not under it. Here is an example, place this into the `handleAccountExistence()` method: `String response = ""; while (response.isEmpty()) { System.out.print("Do you have an account? (y/n - q to quit): -> "); response = scanner.nextLine().trim(); if (!response.matches("(?i)y|n")) { System.out.println("Invalid Entry (" + response + ")! - (y or n required) - Try again...\n"); response = ""; } } if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) { System.out.println(LS + "Enter User Name!"); } else { System.out.println(LS + "Registration Needed!"); }`.

Comment: @Hover to me the Q clearly says (and the code shows) output a prompt then accept input on the same line, not accept input then output something on the same line, so this is _not_ a dupe of 32612888, and the method shown (System.out.print not println then read System.in) _normally_ works. But: **OP:** are you using the console _in Eclipse_ (or possibly another IDE like IDEA or VSCode)? When I run your code with Java I/O to a _terminal_ it works, but with Eclipse the Java I/O is actually connected via _separate pipes_ to Eclipse which allows stderr and stdout data to switch order. ...

Comment: ... Similarly running it remotely over SSH in NON-pty mode (which also uses pipes) does this. I _believe_ VSCode uses SSH but I don't know if it uses pty, and I don't know what IDEA does but it might do either of the methods that fail. OTOH if I change the error message to System.out.println everything stays in correct order, and the prompt allows input on the same line as desired just like a terminal.